# Display Text through Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner at using Javascript or just beginner in general. I'm having a little trouble with this function I created. It is supposed to create a list based on the previous function that I have created.

What I expect is the browser to create a new list every time a input is made with a set of values that were made.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('todoForm')
const todoInput = document.getElementById('todoInput')

if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  let element = document.querySelector('.class-name')
}

let todos = []

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault()

  saveTodo();
})

function saveTodo() {
  const todoValues = todoInput.value;

  let values = {
    value: todoValues,
    checked: false,
    color: '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16),
    length: todoValues.length
  }

  todos.push(values)
  addTask()
}

// add task and adds to the list
function addTask() {
  let task = document.createElement('li')
  task.appendChild(document.getElementById(todos))
}


console.log(todos)
```

```html
<h1 class="title">ToDo List</h1>
<form action="#" class="todoForm" id="todoForm">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Text" id="todoInput" />
  <button id="btn-form" class="btn-form">Enter</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you see the console error?

Comment: Is the result (after adding a bunch of things) meant to be a list of checkboxes? It's not really clear from your question.

Comment: No, there is no console error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you need

1. Added a `<ul>` element to your HTML so you can append there your list of task.
2. `let todoInput = document.getElementById('todoInput')` moved this line inside your `saveTodo()` function becuz you have to get the value of your input right after you press the button, otherwise you will get an empty value
3. have to make a loop to go thru each element pushed to your array then build your list, clear the ul everytime you insert a new element then build again

```js
//script.js
//Const, lets, and var
const form = document.getElementById('todoForm')


//This code only runs on browser
if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  let element = document.querySelector('.class-name')
}

//List

let todos = []
//Values


form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault()

  saveTodo();
})
//Save todo

function saveTodo() {
  let todoInput = document.getElementById('todoInput')
  const todoValues = todoInput.value;

  let values = {
    value: todoValues,
    checked: false,
    color: '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16),
    length: todoValues.length
  }

  todos.push(values)
  addTask()
}

//add task and adds to the list
function addTask() {
  let task = document.getElementById("list");
  task.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
    let li = document.createElement('li')
    li.innerHTML = todos[i].value;
    task.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="html">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="author" content="Nick" />
    <meta name="http-equiv" refresh="2" />
    <script type="module" src="./script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Todo List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="title">ToDo List</h1>
    <form action="#" class="todoForm" id="todoForm">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Text" id="todoInput" />
      <button id="btn-form" class="btn-form">Enter</button>
    </form>
    <ul id="list"></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need clarification on your third point. "make a loop to go thru each element". When you talk about "each element" are you refer to the saveTodo function or the input that the user will put in?

Comment: I refer to your array `todos`, everytime you insert a new task, you push the value into your `todos` array along with other values. In order to build your list based on how many elements you pushed so far in your array, you need to loop thru it. When you insert a new element, the length of your array increases so you have to clear your `<ul>`  before running your loop again or it will duplicate your list plus new element everytime

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few logical errors here.
It sounds like you have a list of `tasks` and it is stored in `todo` variable.
So when you are calling `addTask()` you want it either to receive the (1) new task as an argument or (2)use the `todos` variable.
(1) in this case you need to create a `<li>` list element based on the new task, find `<ul>` element and then append the new one to `<ul>`
(2) clear `<ul>` element, for each task in todos do (1).

As a sidenote:  `let values = {....` should be better called 'value' as it represents a single task.

Comment: Would I need to create two different Elements one being <ul> and the other being <li> since I haven't establish those elements yet using document, createElement('element-name')?

Comment: You can add `<ul>` element in html, but in js is also fine. You know that "li" should be inside "ul", right?